# how to login in gmail using my java swing application?

Tags: java, swing, gmail

I am creating a small email client application using gmail.
For creating a login page i need to authenticate username and password using gmail.
Can somebody help me to code only the authentication part without sending mail
or is there a way to check the given username and password exist in gmail

Comment: google for 'gmail authorizing api'

Answer (score 1):

You have all necessary documentation here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java

---

Part that you are looking for is code section of **"Step 3: Set up the sample"**.